# why generator function in Javascript return true at 3rd time

Tags: javascript, generator

My code

```
function* cal() {
    yield 3;
    yield 5;
}

let calu = cal();
console.log(calu.next())
console.log(calu.next())
console.log(calu.next())
```

Result getting

```
{ value: 3, done: false }
{ value: 5, done: false }
{ value: undefined, done: true }
```

Why generator function returning true at 3rd time, not 2nd console log

Comment: That's the way they're supposed to work. The last value is what is returned by the function. If you add `return 6` to the end of your function, you'd get 6 instead of `undefined`. You have no `return` however, so you do get `undefined`.

Comment: The generator function returns `{ value: undefined, done: true }` at the 3rd time because there are no more yield statements in the generator function. After yielding `5`, the generator function has no more statements to execute, so it automatically returns `{ value: undefined, done: true }`, indicating that it has finished generating values.

Comment: Consider `function* cal() { console.log('a'); yield 3; console.log('b'); yield 5; console.log('c'); }`. Here it's more clear how the generator isn't done yet after yielding `5`. Also try adding `return 'result'` to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.next()` the third time runs the code after the second `yield`. There is none in your example (other than the implicit return), but we can add some:

```js
function* cal() {
    console.log('a');
    yield 3;
    console.log('b');
    yield 5;
    console.log('c');
}

let calu = cal();
console.log(calu.next())
console.log(calu.next())
console.log(calu.next())
```

The second `.next()` call doesn't already return `done: true` because there's still more code to execute. Only after execution has reached the end of the generator function (or a `return` statement), the generator is done.